# Where can I find an editor for "classic" ASP code?

Tags: asp-classic, editor

Where can I find an editor for "classic" ASP code?

Comment: Not a big fan of interdev? :P

Comment: Here's quite a list: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/which-editor-should-i-use-for-developing-asp-applications.html

Comment: you already got notepad.  What else ya need?

Comment: @Russell: ha! Is that thing even *available* anymore? Kinda figured it died with the Java lawsuit...

Comment: @Shog9 - sure is. I have used (within the last year) along with VB6 SP6. :P

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns: I have notepad, but it would be great if there is some editor/IDE for classic asp. Getting lost using notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 SP1

[Visual Interdev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950412.aspx)

Dreamweaver

Answer (score 4):

I always use VS2008 (supports intellisense, highlighting and debugging from SP1) if I'm doing lots of changes, [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) for quick ones (no intellisense, only highlighting)

Answer (score 3):

I am partial to plain old notepad, but notepad++ offers some nice features.

[Notepadd++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

[Here is a codeproject project with intellisense](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/VbScript_Editor_With_Inte.aspx)

Comment: notepad++ wins hands down (except the missing F# syntax highlighting!)

Answer (score 1):

I always used [Text Pad](http://www.textpad.com/) - those were the days..

Answer (score 1):

I have always been a big fan of Dreamweaver for classic ASP. I really like the split screen view to see the code and the designer interface at the same time.

Visual Studio 2008 with the ability to do the split-screen view is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

Although I used to use DreamWeaver or Notepad++, these days I like using VS2008. Mainly because you can attach to process and Debug your ASP code which, when I discovered it, caused me to do a merry jig around the office. You can even get some intellisense. (type Response. and it'll give you all the options .End .Write .Redirect etc..

Answer (score 0):

Although I use VS for coding, in the same genre of Notepad++

[Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/)

Pretty colours, folding, logical projects and tons of other features.

It's the editor I use for opening existing asp code without the hassle of opening VS. (as asp code doesn't necessarily need a recompile)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use TopStyle at work: http://svanas.dynip.com/topstyle/

In addition to classic ASP, it is pretty handy for HTML, CSS, Javascript with syntax highlighting, parens matching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I love Ultra edit for working on classic asp sites, but also any text editing it's great. Lightweight, fast, never crashes.

Only downside is you have to pay for it.